# How to resolve MySQLSyntaxErrorException in JDBC preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I have a query that throws a `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException` and I can't figure out why. I am using xampp and when I try the same query directly, it works fine. I also have a whole bunch of other methods that use very similar queries that all work.
The problem seems to be with updating the date, I noticed in the error message that java puts ' ' around the date, which makes it a string and is probably the reason for the error. However I'm not sure how to fix this to insert the date as a date.

Here's the code:

```
public void update(int userId, String date, String column, String value){
    try {
        // convert date from String to Date
        DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(date);  
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getMillis()); 
        // create prepared statement
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db","root", "");
        String query = "UPDATE expenses_income SET ? = ? WHERE userId = ? AND date = CAST(? AS DATETIME);";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, column);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, value);
        preparedStmt.setInt(3, userId);
        preparedStmt.setDate(4, sqlDate);
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("MySQL exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

And the error message:

```
MySQL exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''comment' = '123' WHERE userId = 1 AND date = CAST('2018-01-06' AS DATETIME)' at line 1
```

I also tried the query without casting as datetime:

```
String query = "UPDATE expenses_income SET ? = ? WHERE userId = ? AND date = ?;";
```

But I get the same error.
I then tried to use `java.util.Date` instead of Joda `DateTime`, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A column name can't be a parameter of the prepared statement.

Comment: Parameters are only for **values**, a column name is not a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. right syntax to use near ''comment' = '123'

You are getting exception because column name parameterization, which is not correct.

```
 UPDATE expenses_income SET ? = ?
```

**It should be**

```
 UPDATE expenses_income SET column_name = ?
```

I also noticed a semicolon `;` at the end of the SQL, which should be removed and you don't need to cast `Date` explicitly. It should be just

```
UPDATE expenses_income SET column_name = ? WHERE userId = ? AND date = ?
```

Also, you shouldn't name column name like `date`, it should be `last_updated` or something meaningful.

Comment: I changed the query to "String query = "UPDATE expenses_income SET ? = ? WHERE userId = " + column + " AND date = CAST(? AS DATETIME);";" But I'm still getting the same error message. EDIT Sorry I just noticed my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @kattapillar You didn't bother to look at my solution. I said, you are suppose to keep column name. Look at my solution carefully.